# K-means cluster analysis with K=2 as a binary classifier

Tags: classification, clustering, k-means

I used two variables, height and weight, and using K-means cluster analysis with $K=2$, two clusters were obtained. I used $K=2$, as the observations either belong to men or women. I then compared the obtained clusters with the real classification. I observed that K-means did pretty well.

Does this sound logical?

Comment: It would be nice to see the height-weight scatterplot of your data, with two sexes coloured differently.

Comment: And a histogram of the attributes; both colored by class and by cluster.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**It depends on what you mean by "did pretty well" and on the population.**  For general adult populations in the developed world I would not expect this to work very well: heights and weights alone are not great at distinguishing the genders.

**The best and easiest way to assess the situation** is to make a scatterplot of height and weight, distinguishing the point symbols by gender.  This one is from the [(US) NHANES 2011-2012 data](http://wwwn.cdc.gov/nchs/nhanes/search/nhanes11_12.aspx), where I have removed data for anyone younger than 18 years.  Note the logarithmic scales, which render each point cloud approximately oval in shape.  (You may guess which kind of symbol--solid red or open blue--corresponds to which gender.)

[image: Figure]

The substantial overlap between the clouds for the two genders (between 160 and 170 centimeters, approximately) shows that no cluster analysis based solely on height and weight could possibly do a very good job discriminating men from women.  The partial lack of overlap, revealed by the cloud of blue above 180 cm and cloud of red below 150 cm, shows that a clustering result would nevertheless have some discriminating power.  Whether this would be good enough depends on your objectives and standards for predictive accuracy.

If, in your dataset, the two clouds appear to have little or no overlap, then not only can you expect a cluster analysis (like K-means) to work well, you can already *see* where the cluster centers should be and where a dividing line ("linear discriminator") would approximately be located.

Here are two k-means solutions for these data: one based on the logarithms and another based on separately standardized heights and weights.  The two clusters are distinguished by the lightness of the symbols.

[image: Figure 2]

(The number of cases shown in these plots is 90 less than the number reported in the first figure due to missing values, which should originally have been excluded.)

Evidently in both cases the clusters, although associated with gender, fail to separate the two colors very well.  The better-looking solution, based on the standardized data, yields these cross-tabulation statistics of cluster and gender:

```
        Cluster
Gender      1    2
  Male   1951  786
  Female  586 2202
```

29% of all males and 21% of all females are mis-classified.

Comment: Shouldn't the variables be standardised before forming clusters?

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to accomplish. With incommensurable variables like height and weight, standardization is ordinarily advisable. With their *logarithms,* though, especially when the variables are expected to be correlated (as they clearly are), standardization is not absolutely necessary and sometimes would not be desirable. Regardless, that makes absolutely no difference in the amount of overlap of the two scatterplots and so would not change your visual assessment of the situation.

Comment: Here, I was trying to check the reliability of the data using 2 means. Can this test be used for this objective?

Comment: I don't know what test you are referring to, nor do I understand how any statistical test performed on such data could tell us about their *reliability*.

Comment: @whuber: (+1) Nice illustration. It would gain a lot if you could actually show, for comparison, how k-means with K=2 splits it into two clusters, but maybe it is too much of a hassle here.

Comment: @amoeba Thank you, that is a good suggestion.  Since I retained the original `R` code to read and process the data, it was a simple matter to compute the k-means solutions and plot them up.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it does sound sensible. I am not sure why you would suspect it did not.

Men tend to be both taller and heavier than women. Exact numbers vary with country ([some data here](http://www.theaveragebody.com/average_weight.php) on weight and [here](http://theaveragebody.com/average_height.php) on height. Combining them ought to make the classification even better.

Answer (score 2):

Be careful of artifacts.

K-means assumes that every attribute has the same weight.

If, say, one attribute is the height in meters, and the other is the weight in g, then the result of k-means will depend almost exclusively on the weight.

If this attribute then is useful for separating your two classes, the outcome will look much more impressive than it is logically.

**Visualize**, visualize, visualize! Often such artifacts can be seen already in a primitive visualization. In your case, I recommend looking at histograms as well as scatterplots; both with class labels and clusters visualized.